# Lock one table at update and another in subquery, which one will be locked first?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET 
col = 'some value' 
WHERE id = X
RETURNING col1, (SELECT col2 FROM table2 WHERE id = table1.table2_id FOR UPDATE);
```

So, this query will lock both tables, `table1` and `table2`, right? But which one will be locked first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution plan for the query will probably look like this:

```
                                        QUERY PLAN                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on laurenz.table1
   Output: table1.col1, (SubPlan 1)
   ->  Index Scan using table1_pkey on laurenz.table1
         Output: table1.id, table1.table2_id, 'some value'::text, table1.col1, table1.ctid
         Index Cond: (table1.id = 42)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  LockRows
           Output: table2.col2, table2.ctid
           ->  Index Scan using table2_pkey on laurenz.table2
                 Output: table2.col2, table2.ctid
                 Index Cond: (table2.id = table1.table2_id)
```

That suggests that the row in `table1` is locked first.

Looking into the code, I see that `ExecUpdate` first calls `EvalPlanQual`, where the updated tuple is locked, and only after that calls `ExecProcessReturning` where the `RETURNING` clause is processed.

So yes, the row in `table1` is locked first.

So far, I have treated row locks, but there are also the `ROW EXCLUSIVE` locks on the tables themselves:

The tables are all locked in `InitPlan` in `execMain.c`, and it seems to me that again `table1` will be locked before `table2` here.

Comment: I notice that I spoke about the row lock, while you seem to be interested in the table locks. I have added information on that.

Comment: No, I interested about row level lock, just missed to note that in question. Anyway, thank you for your answer.